# merge region based on area

Tags: python, numpy, image-segmentation, scikit-image

i need to merge small `regions` from the `Label` product of scikit-image [slic](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.slic) until reach an area regions threshold

the slic itself has a `min_size_factor` which is not the solution in my case because it has unwanted affect at overall result of labeling.

the way i can calc regions area :

```
def pixelcount(regionmask):
    return np.sum(regionmask)
props = regionprops(label_img, extra_properties=(pixelcount,))
```

there is a way same as [cut_normalized](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.future.graph.html#skimage.future.graph.cut_normalized) function (which work on colors similarity of pre-calculated RAG) for regions area?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for someone who may encounter this :

- build a RAG by scikit_image with "pixel count" as data attached to nodes
- define "weight" equal to below code and merge normalize :

  ```
    for x, y, d in graph.edges(data=True):
        diff = graph.nodes[x]['pixel count'] - graph.nodes[y]['pixel count']
        diff = np.linalg.norm(diff)
  ```